# problem with id does not show the correct and repeats

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have a problem with my online shift application:

[image: Table ids]

The user can view their shift requests. The problem is that clicking view (`...`) always redirects to shift `ID 93` in the two registers.

[image: URL with ID]

Controller:

```php
public function inicio() {
    if (Auth::guest()) {
      return redirect()->route("login");
    }

    $config = Configuraciones::findOrFail(0);

    // Solicitudes = REQUEST

    $solicitudes = Solicitudes::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->orderByDesc('created_at')->take(5)->get();

    // GET THE ID OF THE REQUEST FROM THE LOGED USER
    $solicitud = Solicitudes::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->first();

    // GET THE SHIFT 'id' RELATED TO THE 'id' OF THE request
    $eventos = Eventos::where('solicitud_id', $solicitud->id)->first();


    return view('solicitudes.inicio', compact('solicitudes', 'config', 'eventos'))->with($data);
}
```

Blade:

```html
@foreach($solicitudes as $solicitud)
    @if(Auth::user()->id == $solicitud->user_id)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $solicitud->fecha }}</td>
            <td>{{ $solicitud->hora }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                @if($solicitud->estado == '0')
                    <span class="badge badge-primary">Pendiente</span>
                @elseif($solicitud->estado == '1')
                    <span class="badge badge-success">Aceptada</span>
                @elseif($solicitud->estado == '2')
                    <span class="badge badge-danger">Rechazada</span>
                @endif
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-more-horizontal">
                            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1"></circle>
                            <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="1"></circle>
                            <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="1"></circle>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/turno/{{ $eventos->id }}">Ver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Try using: `$eventos = Eventos::where('solicitud_id', $solicitud->id)->get();` but it gives error:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Error:

[image: Error]

What can I do to get the correct shift ID and that the same thing is not always repeated?

Comment: `$eventos` is a collection. You need to loop through the collection to access its properties. Error is from this line probably: `<a class="dropdown-item" href="/turno/{{$eventos->id}}">Ver</a>`

Comment: yes, in that line is the error of the 'id'. How can I go through it?

Comment: Loop through it. `foreach`. If there's only going to be one record belonging to the request solcitud->id, you can change the `get()` to a `first()` and you can continue using `$eventos->id` but make sure you address null situations; `optional($eventos)->id`.

Comment: This didnt fix the error? (referring to the comment you just deleted)

Comment: yes, it fixes it, but it still shows only 'id' 93

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hc1zu6p.png

Comment: Unlike this image, your question shows a `first()` there instead of a `get()`. That said, I think you would benefit from properly defining the relationships. Mind sharing your relationship methods?

Comment: i modify it, try dd($solicitud);   with   ->get() returns the corrects 'id'  Eventos: https://pastebin.com/sKsaE6Cj  Solicitudes Model: https://pastebin.com/SUNdVZnt

Comment: Your relationships look odd. Looks like you have defined `belognsTo` in both models. Since there is solicitud_id in events tables, Solicitude must have many (hasMany) events. If you confirm this I will post an answer with more details.

Comment: yes, please share the answer with more details

Comment: Posted an answer. Sorry it took a while; I was busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted in the comments, first fix your relationship methods.

```
//Solicitudes model
public function eventos(){
  return $this->hasMany(Eventos::class, 'solicitud_id');
}
```

Now when you can include all eventos when you query `Solicitudes` by doing this (notice the use of `with('eventos')`:

```
 $solicitudes = Solicitudes::with('eventos')->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->orderByDesc('created_at')->take(5)->get();
```

And in your blade:

```
@foreach($solicitudes as $solicitud)
    //@if(Auth::user()->id == $solicitud->user_id) => this is redundant since you are already getting solicitudes belonging to the authenticated user so it would be okay to remove
    {{ $solicitud->fecha }}
    @foreach($solictud->eventos as $evento)
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="/turno/{{ $evento->id }}">Ver</a>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The idea here is that each solitude will have its related events loaded.
When you have proper relationships, you can easily fetch related models using `with`. More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Note that I did not check other methods, but I believe this should fix the primary error you highlighted or point you in the right direction.